# How does this php load/download html

Tags: php

So I have .htaccess code which calls out index.php:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase / 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [L,QSA]

<IfModule mod_headers.c>

    Header set X-UA-Compatible "IE=Edge,chrome=1"

    # mod_headers can't match by content-type, but we don't want to send this header on *everything*...

    <FilesMatch "\.(js|css|gif|png|jpe?g|pdf|xml|oga|ogg|m4a|ogv|mp4|m4v|webm|svg|svgz|eot|ttf|otf|woff|ico|webp|appcache|manifest|htc|crx|xpi|safariextz|vcf)$" >

      Header unset X-UA-Compatible

    </FilesMatch>

</IfModule>
```

If i understand this php it defines paths to the directories and files where all the information is
Code:

```
define('WEB_ID', 2);

define('WEB_CATEGORY_ID', 291); 

define('WEB_PRICE_ID', 'cena126'); 
  
// absolute filesystem path to the web root
define('WWW_DIR', dirname(__FILE__));

define('AWOOD_WWW_DIR', WWW_DIR. DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR .'..');
// absolute filesystem path to the application root
define('APP_DIR', WWW_DIR . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR .'app');
// library
define('LIBS_DIR', AWOOD_WWW_DIR . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR. 'library');
// absolute filesystem path to the temporary files
define('TEMP_DIR', WWW_DIR  . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR .  'temp');
// logy
define('LOG_DIR', WWW_DIR  . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR .  'log');

// absolute filesystem path to this web root
$params['wwwDir'] = WWW_DIR;
// absolute filesystem path to the application root
$params['appDir'] = APP_DIR;
// absolute filesystem path to the log
$params['logDir'] = LOG_DIR;
// absolute filesystem path to the library
$params['libsDir'] = LIBS_DIR;
// absolute filesystem path to awood
$params['awoodDir'] = AWOOD_WWW_DIR;

require APP_DIR . '/bootstrap.php';
```

Apparently it somehow calls or downloads html file. Its all on FTP and I cant find any html there.
There is also some javascript but it doesnt seem like this php and .htaccess are calling them so I think its all in that html file that I cant find. I would like to edit that html file. If i understand it correctly it calls it out from some database or is the html file generated?

Im totally new to this so please, dont blame me if im asking nonsense

Comment: PHP is a server-side programming language, normally used as HTML preprocessor. You don't need static HTML, that's the whole point.

Comment: You may find there is some PHP code which generates html or loads it from a database